# Error when trying to upload an image to ImgBB

Tags: node.js, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to upload images to [ImgBB](https://api.imgbb.com/) using NodeJS and GraphQL.
I have a `uploadImage` mutation that takes an image in the form of a data url string, and goes as follows:

```
import parseDataUrl from "data-uri-to-buffer";

// ...

{
  Mutation: {
    async uploadImage(_, { dataUrl }) {
      const buffer = parseDataUrl(dataUrl); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-uri-to-buffer
      
      if (buffer.byteLength > 10 * 10 ** 6)
        throw new Error("The image exceeds the maximum size of 10 MB");

      const body = new FormData();
      body.append("image", buffer);

      const result = await fetch(
        `https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=${process.env.IMGBB_KEY}`,
        {
          method: "post",
          headers: { ...body.getHeaders() },
          body
        }
      ).then<any>(result => result.json());

      if (!result.success || !result.url) {
        const msg = result.error?.message;
        throw new Error(
          `There was an error during upload${msg ? `: ${msg}` : ""}`
        );
      }
      return result.url;
    }
  }
}
```

`body.getHeaders()` contains:

```json
{
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------
------------656587403243047934588601'
  }
```

(I'm using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch))

But no matter the combinations of query params, headers and body I use, I always end up getting this error:

```
  {
    status_code: 400,
    error: { message: 'Undefined array key "scheme"', code: 0 },
    status_txt: 'Bad Request'
  }
```

I can't find anything about it, do you have an idea?

Comment: Can you try this "https://www.npmjs.com/package/imgbb-uploader" or do you must use node-fetch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things you can do to resolve your issue.

1. Important thing with FormData, you need to explicitly provide a name for the image buffer if it's not already included, uploading without name API would throw the same error you have mentioned.

> ```
> body.append("image", buffer, "addSomeImageName.png");
> ```

2. The [api](https://api.imgbb.com/) does not require any header explicitly so you can remove it.

> ```
> {
>     method: "post",
>     headers: { ...body.getHeaders() }, // This can be removed.
>     body
> }
> ```

3. The logic you are using to check for the result is faulty and would always throw error even if the result is successful.

> ```
> if (!result.success || !result.url) {  // Check for success flag only.
>   const msg = result.error?.message;
>   throw new Error(
>     `There was an error during upload${msg ? `: ${msg}` : ""}`
>   );
> }
> ```

This is the block I tested and is working fine:

```js
import parseDataUrl from "data-uri-to-buffer";
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import FormData from "form-data";


async function uploadImage({
  dataUrl
}) {

  const buffer = parseDataUrl(dataUrl);

  if (buffer.byteLength > 10 * 10 ** 6)
    throw new Error("The image exceeds the maximum size of 10 MB");

  const body = new FormData();
  body.append("image", buffer, "someImageName.png");

  const result = await fetch(
    `https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=<your-api-key>`, {
      method: "post",
      // headers: { ...body.getHeaders() },
      body
    }
  ).then(result => result.json())
  // .then(data => {
  //   console.log(data); // Working fine here too.
  // });

  console.log("-------result--------\n", result); // Result is fine.

  // Logic testing.
  console.log(result.success);
  console.log(result.url);
  console.log(!result.success);
  console.log(!result.url);
  console.log(!result.success || !result.url);


  if (!result.success || !result.url) {
    const msg = result.error ? .message;
    console.log(`There was an error during upload${msg ? `: ${msg}` : ""}`)
    // throw new Error(
    //   `There was an error during upload${msg ? `: ${msg}` : ""}`
    // );
  }

  return result.url;
}

console.log("--------------------- console result ------------------------")
console.log(uploadImage({
  dataUrl: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7"
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that seems odd to me:

```
const buffer = parseDataUrl(dataUrl); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-uri-to-buffer
```

The package in the comment only offers the function `dataUriToBuffer`, which you are not using. Are you using `parseDataUrl` from [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/data-urls)? Are you using node-fetch's own implementation of `FormData` as supposed to according to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)?

Please append your question with all relevant `import` statements and please also share the contents of `body.getHeaders()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using the default import from `data-uri-to-buffer`, no issue on that front, it works in other parts of my app. I've upgraded the post with the content of `body.getHeaders()` though you're right I was not using `FormData` from node-fetch. In the meantime, I've switched to S3, so this question is outdated for me.